# Remove item from php array by passing value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => WVSE1P
    [1] => WVSE1MA
    [2] => WVSEU1Y
    [3] => WVSEUP
)
```

how do i remove a particular entry in it by passing the value?

below is the code i tried:

```
$array = $items; //array is items

foreach($array as $key => $value) 
{

$val= 'WVSE1P'; //item to remove
if ($value == $val) unset($array[$key]);

}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) instead of unset so that your array indexes match up correctly after unsetting.

How about this?:

```
$val = 'WVSE1P';
$items = array_splice($items, array_search($val), 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This method removes any values in the specified array without any looping: Example:

```
$array = Array("blue", "orange", "red");

$array = array_diff($array, array("blue")); // blue will be removed

//optionally you can realign the elements:

$array = array_values($array);
```

The reason yours may not work is because you are containing it inside a loop which does not control the array object.

Comment: If he does array_values() at the end, he's going to lose the keys in his array.

Comment: all it does is return the value sin the array and indexes them in order

Comment: Right, but what if he needs to keep the keys? It seems that `$array = array_merge($array)` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Unsetting array items while iterating over that array may cause some unexpected behaviour some times. Here's another solution:

```
$flipped = array_flip($array);
unset($flipped['WVSE1P']);
$array = array_flip($flipped);
```

This should work in this case. Just make sure, that all values are unique within the array.